# How do I render same component depending on the page the user is currently on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called a Card. I render it **twice** on page 1 and page 2 and it displays somewhat different content **depending on the page**. Here is my initial approach.

```
const Card = () => {
const [cardState, setCardState] = useState("firstpage");
  const firstPageProducts = productArray.slice(0, 4);
  const secondPageProducts = productArray.slice(5, productArray.length);
  const [shownImages, setshownImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const shownImages = firstPageProducts.slice(0, 2);
    setshownImages(shownImages);
  }, []);

if (cardState === "firstpage") {
    return (
      <div>
        some first page stuff
      </div>
    );
  } else if (cardState === "secondpage") {
    return (
      <div>
        some second page stuff
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I want it to have a way for it to be **stateless** in a way that I can define from the page in which I'm rendering the card state. I also want it to persist in that if I go back to page 1 it loads correctly page 1 stuff.

right now if I pass down the card state as a prop to the app it sometimes throws an error claiming that the component has not been rendered at all or if it does it changes both the first-page component and the second-page component.  I'm fairly new to react and I've heard of stateless components. I was thinking this has the potential to be one of them.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Props is absolutely the way to do this, show the props code you tried, including the relevant JSX from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is prop. Prop is something passed to `child component` in your case `Card` from parent component like a `Deck` component or something. Idk if that exist in your app.

eg

```
const Deck = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Card cardContent='I am first' productList={[1, 2, 3]} />
            <Card cardContent='I am second' productList={[4, 5, 6]} />
        </div>
    );
};

const Card = ({ cardContent, productList }) => {
    return <div>
       <h1>{cardContent}</h1>
        {productList.map((product) => {
            return <p>{product}</p>
        })}
    </div>;
};
```